how to save the current CPU state in rust
i am trying to add context switching to my first os what is the best method to do so?
i have been trying different methods for a while now, this is my last attempt:
use core::arch::asm;

use crate::serial;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, Default)]
#[repr(C)]
pub struct CPUStatus {
    ss: u64,
    cs: u64,

    rip: u64,

    rbx: u64,
    rax: u64,
    rsp: u64
}


impl CPUStatus {
    pub extern "C" fn save_inner(self) -> Self {
        serial!("{:#?}\n", self);
        self
    }

    pub extern "C" fn save() -> Self {
        unsafe {        
            asm!("
            push rsp
            push rax
            push rbx
            push 0
            push 0x8
            push 0x10
            call {}
            ret
            ", sym Self::save_inner, options(noreturn))
        }
    }
}

output:
CPUStatus {
    ss: 16,
    cs: 8,
    rip: 0,
    rbx: 535719120,
    rax: 0,
    rsp: 1099511713136,
}
kernel panic: page fault exception
frame: TrapFrame {
    insturaction: 16,
    code_segment: 16,
    flags: 8,
    stack_pointer: 66050,
    stack_segment: 1099511713096,
    error_code: 16,
}, at kernel/src/arch/x86_64/interrupts/handlers.rs:67:5


the CPUStatus struct is looking correct however the panic isn't it seems like there is something very wrong with the stack, i don't even think this is a safe enough method

Pretty sure ABI calls for caller-cleanup. So you build up CPUStatus on stack, you call a method on it, it returns and that structure is still there on stack waiting to be cleaned up by caller save. Final ret just reads whatever first structure member was and goes into nowhere land (more specifically, it reads ss which is 0x10 so it would go into eip=0x10 which is consistent with details shown in your panic message)

thanks fixed by putting add rsp, 0x38 after the call, i expected the compiler to automaticlly pop the struct on return
